# How to send email with image background without attach this image as a file for download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email, sendgrid

I send email, it is working as I want, but when the email arrives, it comes with the attached image that I used as the background of my message

This is how I add my image in email

```
<div style="background-image:url('<%= email_bg_tag("bg-email.jpg") %>');background-position:top center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:transparent;">
```

This is my email_helper.erb

```
module EmailHelper
  def email_bg_tag(image)
    attachments[image] = File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/#{image}"))
    attachments[image].url
  end
end
```

My images in `assets/image`

Comment: This isn't going to work in most email clients. The image will be an attachment, but may not display as you want. The coding will not work in Outlook 2007-2019 at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip asset pipeline for static images to work in your emailer, you should put them in:

```
Rails.root + 'public/images'
```

Then in our emailer you should use css with full url to the image:

```
 background-image:url('http://yoursite.com/public/images/background.jpg');
```

I would recommend use style tag in your mailer and just add the class like this:

```
<style>
  .my-fancy-background {
    background-image: url('http://yoursite.com/public/images/bg-email.jpg');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
</style>
<div class="my-fancy-background">
  Here is my email div with some fancy background  
</div>
```

But if you still want helper method, you might also need to set this in application.rb

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://example.com/public/' 
# use public url of your app where your static images can be served from.
```

UPDATE

As per comment by gwally, this may not be supported in Outlook so if you care that this will be supported for Outlook, you might wanna [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779466/html-email-render-in-outlook-vml)

Comment: `background-image` is not supported by Outlook 2007-2019. You need to use VML to display a background image. `div` doesn't behave correctly in Outlook. Email development is not web development.

Comment: @gwally OP doesn't seem to care about that, although you make a valid point. However, feel free to post a better answer if you have one.